# How to create square LED shape by using StaticBox in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to create LED shape in my GUI.

My example code is this.

```
import wx

class Main(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent = None, title ="Static box test")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.myLED = wx.StaticBox(panel, -1, "myLED", pos = (50,50), size = (100,100))
        self.myLED.SetBackgroundColour("blue")
        self.myLED.SetForegroundColour("white")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Main()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The GUI looks like this.

[image]

I wanted to create a square LED having a label in the center of the square.

But the LED doesn't look like a perfect square, and the label is on upper-left side.

How could I fix it?

Comment: wxpython has an LED control ( `wx.lib.gizmos.ledctrl.LEDNumberCtrl` ).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using a **wx.Panel** for the LED and a **wx.StaticText** inside for the text. The answer lies in the use of the Sizers.

Doc: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/sizers_overview.html

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):        
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)        
        self.SetSize((400, 300))

        # The led panel
        self.ledPanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()


    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin: MainFrame.__set_properties
        self.SetTitle("frame")
        self.ledPanel.SetMinSize((100, 100))
        self.ledPanel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(50, 153, 204))

    def __do_layout(self):
        # main sizer which contains the ledPanel (wx.Panel)
        mainSizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(1, 1, 0, 0)
        # the Gridsizer is used to correctly place the label in the center (wx.StaticText)
        myGridSizer = wx.GridSizer(1, 1, 0, 0)

        myLabel = wx.StaticText(self.ledPanel, wx.ID_ANY, "My LED")
        myLabel.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 255))
        myLabel.SetFont(wx.Font(15, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, 0, "Segoe UI"))

        #Adds the label to the sizer:
        myGridSizer.Add(myLabel, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)

        #Sets the sizer to the panel (panel supports background color)
        self.ledPanel.SetSizer(myGridSizer)

        #Adds the panel to the mainSizer.
        mainSizer.Add(self.ledPanel, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)

        # Sets the mainSizer as the main frame sizer
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        mainSizer.AddGrowableRow(0)
        mainSizer.AddGrowableCol(0)

        self.Layout()

# end of class MainFrame

# Class MyApp (to launch my app)
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MainFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

# end of class MyApp


# Main method:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

And this is what you will get when you run it

[image: Example image]

Hope this can help you.